# How to compare two peaks on an indicator in pinescript?

Tags: series, pine-script, algorithmic-trading, back-testing

I am a beginner coder, and I have been creating my own trading strategies in pinescript through tradeview. On the CCI indicator, I have been trying code a strategy where a position would be taken when the current CCI value is greater than the last highest peak, assuming the last peak is greater than 100. I have attached an image of what I mean, with the last highest peak and where I would have taken position highlighted.[CCI position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUt6Z.jpg)

My initial thoughts:
cci_low = valuewhen(cci>100,cci(close,20),0)
cci_high = valuewhen(cci>cci_low and cci(close,20),0)

My initial thought was to compare the moment when the indicator CCI crosses the 100 mark to the next CCI that also has crossed the 100 mark, and save the highest CCI value. However, my experience is limited, and I could not figure out how to set a condition where I compare the initial cci value that is > 100 to the current CCI value that is > than the initial CCI only after there is a dip below the 100 mark. Simply, I wish to take a position only when the later CCI has surpassed the last highest CCI peak, with a peak defined as having a retrace down beneath the 100 mark.

I also tried using the barssince() function, where I would search for the initial CCI that is > 100, i.e., barssince(CCI>100), obtain the CCI value through CCI(close,20)[barssince(CCI>100)] and compare this value to the current CCI. However, that still would not address the highest peak issue, and pinescript does not allow series integer from barssince() to be used in such a way.

Any help and advice would truly be greatly appreciated.

Thank you, Thomas